# XSL XML to CSV position number

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

I'am newbie in XSL i have an xml file like above and i would like to transform it to csv i use java main to execute it  but i has a problem with geting position number in xsl file

```
<parent>
    <child name="a" type="1"/>

    <child name="b" type="2"/>

    <child name="c" type="1"/>

    <child name="d" type="3"/>

</parent>
```

The output is :

```
a     1
b     2
c     1
d     3
```

but what i would like to get is :

```
 child name type
     1    a     1 
     2    b     2
     3    c     1
     4    d     3
```

with the first column should be the child position

this is my xsl file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="child">
 <!--header row-->
  <xsl:for-each select="child">
  <xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

  </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="@*">

    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So to summarize i have two problem how can add header row like the example and how can get position of child and add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in other answers, your main problem is context: you must be in the context of `parent` in order to do `<xsl:for-each select="child">`.

If you want this to be dynamic, including the header row, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <!-- header row-->
    <xsl:for-each select="*[1] | *[1]/@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>   
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- body -->
    <xsl:for-each select="*">   
        <xsl:number/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat()` as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="'child;name;type'"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ';',@name, ';', @type)"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You better match the parent, print the header row, then loop over the children:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="parent">
 <!--header row-->
    <xsl:text>child;name;type&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="child">
        <xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```