# XML ro CSV xslt child of child

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I return to you because i have another problem and i don't find a solution, according to my question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402693/xsl-xml-to-csv-position-number/32403031#32403031)

now i have a childofchild like you can see above :

```
<parent>
    <child name="a" type="1">
     <childOfChild id="1" t="a"/>
      <childOfChild id="3" t="h"/>
       <childOfChild id="1" t="k"/>
</child>
    <child name="b" type="2">
   <childOfChild id="6" t="p"/>
</child>
    <child name="c" type="1"/>

    <child name="d" type="3"/>

</parent>
```

what i would like to do is this :

```
child    name type  ChildOfChild          id   t
 child 1    a     1  ChildOfChild1        1    a
 child 1    a     1  ChildOfChild2         3    h
 child 1    a     1  ChildOfChild3         1    k
 child 2    d     3  ChildOfChild1         6    p
```

Someone have any idea please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/parent">
    <xsl:text>name&#9;t&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="child/childOfChild">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@t"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
name    t
a       a
a       h
a       k
b       p
```